# How can I delay the loading of CSS background images?

Tags: javascript, css, image, optimization, dom

I am animating sprites in a HTML/JavaScript game by showing/hiding/repositioning many divs, each with a CSS background image.

I'd like to load some of the images only when they are first needed, rather than loading them all when the page is first loaded.

Will setting them all to "display:none" initially and then showing/hiding them with "display:inline" do this?

Or should I append and remove the divs as needed?  Or is there another way to do this?

(I've already optimized the image file sizes using various tools, so this question is specifically about finding a way to load the images as needed with HTML/JS rather than all at once.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by storing the URLs for the background images in an associative array and retrieving them when you wish to apply them to the `backgroundImage` style of the div.

Example:

```
var resources = {div1:"url(image1.png)",div2:"url(image2.png)",div3:"url(image3.png)"};

function loadImageBG(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = resources[id];
}
```

where

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

are the divs you wish to supply background images for.

Comment: Nitpick: the term in JavaScript would be “object” rather than “associative array”.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html I know the name for the term. I used "associative array" to illustrate a point and teach a principle. I might as easily (and correctly) have called it a hash. If I call my car "my ride" you know what I'm talking about, and you knew what I was talking about here.

Comment: Oh, fair play, I just thought the term “array” might be confusing here given that JavaScript has a specific object called an array. You’re right though, it doesn’t practically matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your CSS properties dynamically using Javascript instead of a static .css file.

Here is an example to add and remove styles:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>add/remove style</title>
    <script>
        function removeStyle(id){
            var cs = document.getElementById(id);
            cs && cs.parentNode.removeChild(cs);
        }
        function addStyle(css, id){
            removeStyle(id);
            var styleNode = document.createElement("style");
            styleNode.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
            styleNode.setAttribute('id', id);
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleNode);
            if(typeof styleNode.styleSheet !=='undefined'){
                styleNode.styleSheet.cssText = css; //IE
            }else{
                styleNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>text to color</p>
    <input onclick="addStyle('p{color:#900}p{background:#DEF}', 'myStyle')" 
        type="button" value="add style" >
    <input onclick="removeStyle('myStyle')" type="button" value="remove style">
</body>
</html>
```

The addStyle/removeStyle functions will probably need some rework in your case, but you get inside the important stylesheet functions to use.